# In EF5, how to create a field that will be read but not inserted or updated

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I don't want the functionality from [NotMapped] - I want it to read in a value if set, but never update the value. I'm essentially after the equivalent of `<property update="false" insert="false" ... />` in NHibernate.

Is this possible with Entity Framework?

What I am trying to do is have a DateTime column 'CreateStamp' set to the current DateTime on insert.

Here is what I have.

Configuration:

```
Property(s => s.CreateStamp)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);
```

Migration script (is applied):

```
CreateStamp = c.DateTime(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "GETDATE()"),
```

The property is defined in the class as:

```
public DateTime?    CreateStamp { get; set; }
```

The query EF generates is trying to insert NULL into the CreateStamp column.

Comment: Please try it with `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` instead of `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed`.

Comment: @nemesv I tried that, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a store-generated value. You can set `StoreGeneratedPattern` to [Computed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.storegeneratedpattern.aspx) on that field.

Comment: Hi Craig. I've tried that already - I just updated the question with what I have. It is still trying to insert into that column.